# Can abilities target themselves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am new to the game sorry for the rookie question. Can abilities (both activated and triggered) target themselves?

Comment: Welcome to the game (and the site)! Can you give an example of the type of ability you are talking about? I ask because this is more of an advanced question than a rookie one, and it's at least possible that due to common rookie terminology mix-ups, you aren't asking the same question you actually intended to.

Comment: What prompts you to ask this? I agree with Gendolkari completely. This is almost always not a situation a newbie would face; very few things can actually target an ability and none of the ones I know are, themselves, an ability. It's more likely you have a specific situation in mind but you're using incorrect vocabulary to describe it -- that is, in fact, not all that uncommon for a newbie at all, and also nothing to be ashamed of since the game can be pretty confusing at the beginning. Could I suggest you clarify what exact cards you have in mind, and how you imagine them interacting?

Comment: Are you asking: "Can a creature target itself with its ability?" or "Can an ability target itself on the stack?" or some other derivation?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. The question is clear to me: Can an ability target itself? If the author wants to ask a different question, then the author can ask a different question.

Comment: @Rainbolt That is a clear question but it's not clear that's what OP intended to ask. Some clarification from OP would go a long way.

Comment: I think this needs clarification because it's just so rare that this question would even come up, especially at a beginner level, that there is a high probability that something else was intended. As far as I can tell, there have only ever been two cards with abilities that could target themselves. And the activating player wouldn't even want to do that with those cards.

Answer (score 6):

No, abilities cannot target themselves. This is specified by [rule 114.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Target):

> A spell or ability on the stack is an illegal target for itself.

Answer (score 2):

While murgatroid is correct, to answer a related question that you *might* be trying to ask, if a permanent (creature, enchantment, land, etc) has some kind of ability, then the permanent *may* be a legal target for its own ability. For example, Merror Levitator has the ability "Tap: Target creature gains flying until end of turn", and Guardian of Solitude has "Whenever you cast a Spirit or Arcane spell, target creature gains flying until end of turn." It's fine to tap Merror Levitator to give it flying, and similarly if you cast a Spirit or Arcane spell then Guardian of Solitude will happily do the same.